# Multiple columns in OVER ORDER BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, row-number

Is there a way to specify multiple columns in the OVER ORDER BY clause?

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (A.Col1)) AS ID FROM MyTable A
```

The above works fine, but trying to add a second column does not work.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (A.Col1, A.Col2)) AS ID FROM MyTable A
```

> Incorrect syntax near ','.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The problem is the extra parentheses around the column name.  These should all work:

```
-- The standard way
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.Col1) AS ID FROM MyTable A
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.Col1, A.Col2) AS ID FROM MyTable A

-- Works, but unnecessary
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (A.Col1), (A.Col2)) AS ID FROM MyTable A
```

Also, when you ask an SQL question, you should always specify which database you are querying against.

Answer (score 2):

No brackets.

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.Col1, A.Col2) AS ID FROM MyTable A
```