# How to rank records based on the maximum value across in a field?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Data in the table

```
ID  attempt1  attempt2   attempt3
1      2.00      2.10      1.99
2      2.15      2.01      1.80
3      1.85      2.05      1.98
```

Expected result

```
ID  attempt1  attempt2   attempt3   rank
2      2.15      2.01      1.80       1
1      2.00      2.10      1.99       2
3      1.85      2.05      1.98       3
```

Query to achieve result

```
select ID, attempt1, attempt2, attempt3, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY attempt1, attempt2, attempt3) 
AS rank FROM Attempts
```

The query above works fine when I attempt to rank the values in one column say attempt1, but when I add the additional fields the ranking does not work the correct way. I am not sure what you be causing this. I tried the following solution [Multiple columns in OVER ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11691046/multiple-columns-in-over-order-by) but it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to derive the "max score for that row" outside of the `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

What you've written so far orders the rows by `attempt1`, then where there are tyies, order by `attempt2`, and where there are still ties, order by `attempt3`.

The query below uses a sub-query in an `APPLY` so as to use `MAX()` across three columns in a single row.  The result of which can then be used in the `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```
SELECT
  attempts.ID,
  attempts.attempt1,
  attempts.attempt2,
  attempts.attempt3,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY max_score.val DESC)   AS rank
FROM
  attempts
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT MAX(score) AS val
    FROM (VALUES (attempts.attempt1),
                 (attempts.attempt2),
                 (attempts.attempt2)) attempt(score)
)
  max_score
```

Comment: Good solution and thanks for the explanation to aid my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to calculate the maximum value across the fields.

In SQL Server 2008, I think I would do:

```
select t.*,
       row_number() over (order by v.max_attempt desc) as seqnum
from attempts t cross apply
     (select max(attempt)
      from (values (t.attempt1), (t.attempt2), (t.attempt3)) v(attempt)
     ) v (max_attempt);
```

Comment: Is this solution applicable to sql server 2012

Comment: The DESC key word is missing form the order by clause. Adding the DESC keyword solved the problem.